# How do you aggregate (sum, average, etc.) the values that share a certain attribute in the index of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame>` that looks something like this

```
Date           Count1    Count2
2020-01-01     11        23
2020-02-01     13        24
2020-01-11     12        22
2020-04-01     43        13
...
```

What do I need to do if I want to get the average or sum of the rows that appear in Jan (or any certain boolean condition)?

Answer (score 0):

- 1. generate a toy pandas DataFrame

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime



basedata = pd.DataFrame({'month':np.random.randint(low=1, high=4, size=10),
'day': np.random.randint(low=1, high=20, size=10)})

basedata['date'] = basedata.apply(lambda x: datetime(year=2020, month=x['month'], day=x['day']), axis=1)
basedata['count1'] = np.random.randint(low=10, high=30, size=10)
basedata['count2'] = np.random.randint(low=20, high=30, size=10)
basedata = basedata.drop(['month', 'day'], axis=1)
basedata
```

[image]

- 2. if you want to calculate the data for each month,you can write such code:

```py
basedata.groupby(basedata['date'].dt.month).agg({'count1':['sum', 'count', 'mean'], 'count2':['sum', 'count']})
```

[image]

- 3. if you want to filter data by month. see below code:

```py
basedata.loc[basedata['date'].dt.month ==1, :]
```

[image]

Comment: I created a new question based on my new requirements. Thanks for the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488448/how-can-i-aggregate-sum-mean-etc-values-and-create-a-new-pandas-dataframe-b