# How can I aggregate (sum, mean, etc.) values and create a new Pandas dataframe based on that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe `<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame>` that has multiple date columns.

```
Year           Month          Count1    Count2
2015-01-01     2015-05-01     11        23
2015-01-01     2015-03-01     13        24
2020-01-01     2020-05-01     12        22
2020-01-01     2020-05-01     43        13
...
```

So, it indicates that the second row falls into March in the month category and 2015 in the year category. What I want to do is create a new dataframe that aggregates (let's do sum) the rows that fall into the same category.

For example, if I want to aggregate by year

```
Month          Count1    Count2
2015-05-01     11        23
2020-01-01     55        35
...
```

by month, it will be like

```
Month          Count1    Count2
2015-01-01     24        47
2015-03-01     13        24
2020-05-01     55        35
...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation can be done by;

```
agg_col = "Year"

new_df = df.groupby(by=agg_col, as_index=False).agg({"Count1": "sum", "Count2": "sum"})
```

And you can change `agg_col` to `Month` if you want to group by month.

Comment: can I do `df2 = df.groupby(by=agg_col, as_index=False).agg({"Count1": "sum", "Count2": "sum"})` or will this modify df?

Comment: Sure, the code you wrote will not modify the original df, and create a new aggregated one. Am changing the answer to be more clear.